# Finding suitable area using raster in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro

I have 2 raster data:
-land use (water, urban, agriculture, forest)
- risk categories (low, medium, high)

How can I find out the land use category that falls on the medium+high risk using raster in ArcGIS Pro?

I thought of classifying medium risk and high risk as 1, combine them, and get a raster dataset of medium+high risk together.

But then, how can I find out the mostly landuse type that falls into this zone (medium+high risk)?

Comment: I know that, but i just don't know how to find out the dominant landuse type that falls over the medium+high risk layer. I reclassified medium risk as 1, and high risk as 1. i boolean AND them and I got a new layer, which is supposed to be medium risk + high risk. And from now I am stuck in finding out the most landuse type that is situated over this layer. I tried to do it old fashion, and to just look at it, but the solving requires theory.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but *precisely* what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  A picture will probably help to make what you are asking clearer.

Comment: Try the [Combine](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/combine.htm) tool.